# HTML - Flexbox must be used only with <div> elements?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So far I have seen that all examples using flexbox have been used into *div* elements, both for the container and for the items. For example:

```
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item">One</div>
   <div class="flex-item">Two</div>
   <div class="flex-item">Three</div>
</div>
```

My question is: **Can i use flexbox in any html tag?**
Imagine that instead of using *div* tag I want to use *ul* for creating a navbar, could I use it here as well or should I surround each *li* with a *div* tag?

```css
.flex-container { display:flex; }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#">PRICES</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: why don't you try this out in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: You *can* but there are some it would be unwise to do so... `table` for instance etc,

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [yes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox#the_flex_container)

```css
.flex-container { 
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.flex-item { margin-right:25px; }
ul {list-style-type:none; }
a { text-decoration:none }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="flex-container">
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#">COURSES</a></li>
    <li class="flex-item"><a href="#">PRICES</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What did you mean in your comment with 'ilegal HTML'. I am new in StackOverflow and do not know much about how it works :)

Comment: Wrapping an LI in a div is invalid HTML - sorry if I confused you

Answer (score -1):

Yes, flexbox can be used with  any html tag and the `<div>` is most commonly used as a flex container...You can use `display: flex;` on a `ul`, or any other html tag.

Comment: I apologize for this, I am new to this community so i didnt know about it, i would keep this in mind the next time I answer someone's question... thank you for pointing that out :)